# Codeception for Laravel 5: really interesting?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, codeception

Codeception had a real appreciation on Laravel 4 by proposing an architecture of acceptances tests easier and complete

**But when is it for Laravel 5?**

When I see that Laravel 5 is capable of this test

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->visit('/')
         ->click('About Us')
         ->seePageIs('/about-us');
}
```

I wonder if codeception is always interesting for Laravel 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it is not always interesting since Laravel already provides a very nice [fluent wrapper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing) for PHPUnit. Codeception also uses PHPUnit as a backend for running test.

http://codeception.com/docs/05-UnitTests

I don't think they differ that much but you should compare a bit.